# Custom Control BorderThickness

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, user-controls, border

I've created a custom WPF user control. The problem is, that sometimes I need a BorderThickness of 0 and sometimes a BorderThickness of 1.

```
<UserControl ...>
   <clay:TextBox x:Name="ClayTextBox" 
            BorderThickness="1" >
   </clay:TextBox>
</UserControl>
```

If I'm using the control in a xaml document like this:

```
<clay:TextBox x:Name="ClayTextBox" 
    BorderThickness="0" >
 </clay:TextBox>
```

... the Border is always 1. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom control template style, you should set the parent container control as border and then use template binding to bind the border thickness. Here I've assumed that your CustomControl inherits a control that has BorderThickness as a property.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type clay:TextBox}">
    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          //Remaining xaml that makes up your custom control.
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your border Bind its BorderThickness propety to the UserControls one like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UseRcontrolWithProperty.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="this"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
          <Border BorderThickness="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=BorderThickness}"></Border>  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

that way changing the BorderBrush on the UserControl will change the border brush of the internal border.